# What is the best way to transfer BigQuery data to SFTP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, etl, serverless

The data is a few hundred Mb up to a few Gb. It could be running some BQ procedures and in the end a select. The values of this need to be transferred as a valid CSV to an SFTP.

Cloud functions could be problematic because of the 9 minute timeout limit and the 2Gb RAM limit.

Is there a serverless solution or do I have to run manual instances?

Comment: How many memory do you need?

Answer (score 3):

There are two scenarios I would consider:

1. Export table with standard BQ options ([here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#bq)) into **GCP bucket storage**. Then you can pick it up and upload it to SFTP by [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run). There are containers, which are built for this, e.g. [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/atmoz/sftp)
2. Run a pipelining project. Considering you want to use simple export, I would suggest [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs). You can write a small Python or Java code to pick up a file and upload it to SFTP. If you would like more complex logic in processing - have a look at [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc)